# Selenium c# check if ::before is available inside span or not

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to check if ::before is available inside a span tag or not. If ::before is available that means checkbox is checked. If not checkbox is not checked. How do I determine this using selenium.

[image]

[image]

I got to know it is a pseudo text. So I need to rely on JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried with `.find_elements` with `.span[title='CHK_AdvanceArrears']::before` and checked the number of elements returned?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is .span[title='CHK_AdvanceArrears']::before using css selector?